# Responsive position sticky

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I have sticky header disappearing when scrolling down on mobile devices and appearing again when scrolling up. But it is working just fine on other devices. Please help here is my HTML and CSS.

```css
.top_header {
  padding-top: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f4eade;
}

.header{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  z-index: 110;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: -o-sticky; 
  position: -webkit-sticky;         
  top: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4.5px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid top_header">
<div class="row">
    <!--  -->
</div>
</div>
<div class="header navbar navbar-expand-lg">

</div>
```

Comment: its ether based on an `css` media query or `js` which is not provided ?

Comment: Css, I did not use JS for this

Comment: seems to be working fine. Whats the device u tested on ? https://jsfiddle.net/pam150uk/1/

Comment: On PC, on chrome's developer mode reponsive test

Comment: Sorry Guys, the problem was in my chrome. I tested it in my phone and it is working just fine ;) Sorry one more time!

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just use position fixed?

```
.name-element {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: It is a good idea, but I have 2 header, Main and Secondary. If I use fixed position to my main header, it will stick on top of the page and user cannot see secondary header. That's why I need to use Position sticky to my Main header. I can use fixed position to achieve this kind of functionality but using JS. I read in some blogs that js is a bad idea for this kind of thing. Because it would involve a scroll event listener, which is still a very expensive thing to add to app. They said it is hard to maintain a solid 60 FPS on mobile devices.

Comment: And what if you just put a <div> around the 2 headers? That way you can make them both fixed?

Comment: I cant because one of the must disappear while scrolling